# Does the set mZ form a group under addition when m is a real number??

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

m**Z** is the set of all integers multiplied by m when m is any **real** number.

i.e, m**Z**={...,-2m,-m,0,m,2m,...}

Does m**Z** form a group under addition when m is ***any*** **real** number??

( I know that it forms a group under addition when m is a positive integer. But does it hold when m is any real number as well??)

Comment: Yes, $m\Bbb Z$ is a group for any $m \in \Bbb R$. In fact, $m\Bbb Z$ is the subgroup of $\Bbb R$ generated by $m$.

Answer (score 1):

If you think about the proof that $m\mathbb{Z}$ is a group under addition for integer $m$, you should see that nothing about the proof uses the fact that $m$ is an integer.

Any $mk,mj \in m\mathbb{Z}$ add to $m(k+j) \in m\mathbb{Z}$, $mk$'s inverse is $-mk = m(-k)$, $0 = m\cdot 0\in m\mathbb{Z}$, and addition is associative because it is for integers.

That's rather terse, but you should know the proof, just mentioning the details again, each step holds for any $m\in \mathbb{R}$ that you like, not just $m\in \mathbb{Z}$.